# How to find increasing sequence in list by python3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
list= [3, 8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 0, 7, 4, 8, 3, 3, 7, 8, 8]
```

The decomposition of L into increasing sequences, with consecutive duplicates removed.

Result:

```
[[3, 8], [2, 5, 7], [1], [0, 7], [4, 8], [3, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the naivest approach:

1. Append items one by one into a list.
2. If duplicate of the previous item found, skip. Otherwise, if the current item is less than the previous one, append the current list to another list and the current item to a new list.
3. Repeat step 3 until you reach the end of the list.